# How to create application in IIS using Wix?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am beginner in MSI creation. I am using WIX 3.5.I want to create an application directory in IIS on installation of MSI. Currently I am using below code -

```
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="IISMain" Name="inetpub">
        <Directory Id="WWWMain" Name="wwwroot">
          <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="ServicesTest"></Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

But this code is creating virtual directory name - "ServicesTest", not application directory. How could I create an application directory using WIX?

Comment: Any reason you're using version 3.5 when 3.9 has been released more than a month ago?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this article from Bart de Mayer:
http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/

And here are the files to the article:
https://github.com/BartDM/WIXInstallerDemo/tree/master/DemoWebsite.Setup

Comment: Linking to other websites is better than nothing, but an ideal answer is to place the proper examples directly in your answer to protect against dead links.